# how to stop attacking website with (cmd curl) in php files

Tags: php, curl, cmd

fogive me for my poor english.the question is below:

someone use cmd:curl ******,to attack my website with Proxy ip address. so that i can't judge whether the click action from the ip adderss which it has been used. so i would like some php code can judge the action from my website or cross-realm submit, and only alowed local action.

thanks a lot.

Comment: what does clicking has to do with php? You obviously can get IP of request client with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Please add more details, does your page have a form? If so, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975990/prevent-remote-script-using-php-curl-from-logging-into-website

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to survive a DDoS attack is to make your network service more robust and efficient, you can't make your system more adaptable with PHP alone.

You might find these links helpful:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750213.aspx
- http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/what_can_companies_do_to_stop_a_ddos_attack.php

Comment: first,thankyou for your answer.i will try to make my problem more  obviously. my site got two files, one named form.html and another named action.php.user can POST their infomation in form.html,and action.php will  recieve the POST.in normal,i use $_POST[] can get all what i want. but someone use CMD: curl -F name=XXX -F age=18 http://url ,can also send informations. so i have to write some php code to judge thether the information is normal POST or from CMD. and  filter the information from CMD.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an hidden element in you form, the value of that element could be a timestamp or some kind of unique id, so this way, you can check if the request comes from your form and handle it.